# make always passes the same input-file

Tags: windows, compilation, makefile

I'm trying to compile a large project with GNU-Win make under Windows 7.

```
CCFLAGS = -D__forceinline -D__GCC__ -D__PC -Wno-multichar -DCOMPILE_CODEBLOCKS -Wattributes -Winvalid-offsetof
SOURCES = $(wildcard c4d/*.cpp)
OBJECTS = $(subst .cpp,.o,$(subst c4d/,c4d/obj/,$(SOURCES)))

all: $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJECTS):$(SOURCES)
    python pr.py $< $@
```

The `python pr.py` program just prints all passed commands to the command-line. (`@echo` and `echo` don't work?!)

But what I see in the console is this:

```
python pr.py c4d/c4d_basebitmap.cpp c4d/obj/c4d_basebitmap.o

c4d/c4d_basebitmap.cpp
c4d/obj/c4d_basebitmap.o

python pr.py c4d/c4d_basebitmap.cpp c4d/obj/c4d_basechannel.o

c4d/c4d_basebitmap.cpp
c4d/obj/c4d_basechannel.o

python pr.py c4d/c4d_basebitmap.cpp c4d/obj/c4d_basecontainer.o

c4d/c4d_basebitmap.cpp
c4d/obj/c4d_basecontainer.o

python pr.py c4d/c4d_basebitmap.cpp c4d/obj/c4d_basedocument.o

c4d/c4d_basebitmap.cpp
c4d/obj/c4d_basedocument.o

python pr.py c4d/c4d_basebitmap.cpp c4d/obj/c4d_basedraw.o

c4d/c4d_basebitmap.cpp
c4d/obj/c4d_basedraw.o

python pr.py c4d/c4d_basebitmap.cpp c4d/obj/c4d_baseeffectorplugin.o

c4d/c4d_basebitmap.cpp
c4d/obj/c4d_baseeffectorplugin.o

python pr.py c4d/c4d_basebitmap.cpp c4d/obj/c4d_baselist.o

c4d/c4d_basebitmap.cpp
c4d/obj/c4d_baselist.o

python pr.py c4d/c4d_basebitmap.cpp c4d/obj/c4d_basematerial.o

c4d/c4d_basebitmap.cpp
c4d/obj/c4d_basematerial.o
```

You can see, that the input file is always `c4d/c4d_basebitmap.cpp` while the output file always differs (as desired).

Why is the input file always the same?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the dependencies between sources and objects set up as $< always evaluates to the first dependency. http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables

Comment: AFAICR (I'm rusty on this level of detail), the `$<` really only works reliably in a suffix rule such as `.cpp.o:` or in the wild-card equivalent (`%.o : %.cpp`).  In other places where it is used, you get some not-necessarily-useful value, such as (in this case), the first source file.  Note that your rule says "recompile every object file when any one of the source files changes"; this is probably not what you wanted.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you! Does it? But what would say something like "recompile the ones that changed"? PS: I don't get the latter form. When I replace the second target with `%.o : %.cpp` it tells me that there is not rule to build target "c4d/obj/c4d_basebitmap.o". Same with `.cpp.o:`

Comment: Probably a simple `%.o : %.cpp` rule (with the action being your current command line). Since `all` depends on `$(OBJECTS)`, you don't need anything else, I think. OTOH, since you say that doesn't work, it is probably something to do with the pathname components. I take the simple-minded approach: when all else fails, write it out long-hand. I'm not allowed to use GNU Make on all platforms, so I don't know all the ins and outs of it; I have to work with the lowest common denominator, which is painful on occasion. I'd have to experiment to give advice, and I'm chronically out of round tuits.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler But make tells me there is no rule to build target "xxx.o" when using `%.o : %.cpp` instead of `$(OBJECTS) : $(SOURCES)`. :o

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I could find out why `%.o : %.cpp` doesn't work. `make` expects the `.cpp` lieng in `c4d/obj/` because the target should be there, too. Do you know how I can make my object-files to be at an `obj/` subdir?

Comment: Try `c4d/obj/%.o: c4d/%.cpp`.